# knockout.js/devExtreme unable to process css-binding

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, phonejs, devextreme

I have a dxTileView template which is databound to data coming in from the server. Then, in the template I want to add a css binding which adds a class when the tile is clicked like so...

```
<div data-bind="dxTileView: {itemClickAction:assignProject, dataSource:quickBooking}">
          <div data-options="dxTemplate : { name:'item' }" data-bind="css: {selectedTile: selectedTile}">
            <h4 data-bind="text: blah"></h4>
            <p data-bind="text: blah"></p>
          </div>
</div>
```

And then in the viewmodel I have:

```
var viewModel = {
        selectedTile: ko.observable(false),
        blah: blah}
```

And the error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "css: function (){return {selectedTile:selectedTile} }"
Message: selectedTile is not defined
```

I have tried a few variations on my bindings as follows but none work:

```
data-bind="css: {selectedTile: viewModel.selectedTile}"//error: viewModel not defined
data-bind="css: {selectedTile: viewModel.selectedTile()}"
data-bind="css: {selectedTile: true}" //this works,was just for testing
data-bind="css: {selectedTile: selectedTile(false)}"//etc etc etc
```

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You can try with data-bind="css: {selectedTile: $root.selectedTile}"

Comment: @GôTô - that did it! Can you convert to an answer please so I mark as answered and correct? Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the root of your view model, use `$root`.

Try this:

```
data-bind="css: {selectedTile: $root.selectedTile}"
```

Comment: pants, now the binding applies to every tile when I try to process it through the onclick event. I guess I really need to change up my datasource to keep it unique to the selected tile

Comment: `selectedTile` sounds like it should hold an id or an object rather than a boolean :)

Comment: I'm so close but just can't get there, any chance of a gentle push? I assume you mean in the viewmodel `selectedTile` should hold an id or object?

Comment: Yes and then compare it to your current object in your binding like `data-bind="css: {selectedTile: $root.selectedTile() == myTileId()}"`

Comment: goddammit I could've sworn I tried that earlier, I suppose I must have had it different somehow! Thanks so much for all your help!